# Magento 2 How to create log of upgrade command?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, debugging

I wanted to create `logs` of upgrade command under `var/log` folder:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below command:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
```

It may help you.

Comment: It worked. Thankyou :)